# CGContext errors while trying to convert text to image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cgcontext

I am trying to convert text to an image and using that image as a subview. However I get a few errors. I got the piece of script from another stackoverflow post;

```
/* Creates an image with a home-grown graphics context, burns the supplied string into it. */
- (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
    
    CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [img drawInRect:aRectangle];
    
    [[UIColor redColor] set];           // set text color
    NSInteger fontSize = 14;
    if ( [text length] > 200 ) {
        fontSize = 10;
    }
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize];     // set text font
    
    [ text drawInRect : aRectangle                      // render the text
             withFont : font
        lineBreakMode : UILineBreakModeTailTruncation  // clip overflow from end of last line
            alignment : UITextAlignmentCenter ];
    
    UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
    return theImage;
}
```

I call this piece of code with the code:

```
[self burnTextIntoImage:textInsert :textImage];
```

The errors I get are:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetTextMatrix: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFontSize: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetTextPosition: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: This is a strange name for method. From it's name, I'd expect the image parameter to be first and the text parameter second. Are you sure you didn't accidentally mix them up? How do you really call the method? The calling line in your question will hardly compile.

Comment: How do you think I should call the method then? I just use the one written above where textInsert is a nsstring with the text I want to compile and textImage is an UIImage which I'm using to display the compiled text image.

Comment: In a method name, the word (or words) right before each colon usually indicates the type of the parameter right after the colon. So a good name would be `(UIImage *)burnText: (NSString*)text intoImage:(UIImage *)image`. (BTW: After looking at the calling line for the fourth time, I've figured out that I was probably wrong and that it compiles. Your method name is just too confusing for me.)

Comment: I've changed it, but it still doesn't work. I get the same errors as before.

Comment: There's no obvious mistake in the posted code. So the problem could be that the `img` parameter is `nil` (have you checked this) or that you aren't running the code on the main thread.

Comment: The img seemed to be nil, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
////Drawing text using Quartz 2D in an iOS application

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

{

  CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGRect viewBounds = self.bounds;



  CGContextTranslateCTM(theContext, 0, viewBounds.size.height);

  CGContextScaleCTM(theContext, 1, -1);



  // Draw the text using the MyDrawText function

  MyDrawText(theContext, viewBounds);
}

 ////Drawing text
void MyDrawText (CGContextRef myContext, CGRect contextRect) // 1

{

float w, h;

w = contextRect.size.width;

h = contextRect.size.height;



CGAffineTransform myTextTransform; // 2

CGContextSelectFont (myContext, // 3

                "Helvetica-Bold",

                 h/10,

                 kCGEncodingMacRoman);

CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, 10); // 4

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFillStroke); // 5



CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, .5); // 6

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, 1); // 7

myTextTransform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  (MyRadians (45)); // 8

CGContextSetTextMatrix (myContext, myTextTransform); // 9

CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, 40, 0, "Quartz 2D", 9); // 10

UIImage *theImage=  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

For more visit following link...

[How Quartz 2D Draws Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html)

Hope, this will help you....chill...

Answer (score 0):

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
...
```

There is no active graphics context. IOW, you are requesting the draw, but there is no operator or destination.

You need to perform this call when a graphics context exists locally (e.g. when `drawRect:` is called), or you must create a context explicitly for the process (e.g. `CGBitmapContextCreate`).

If you're using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, that should be from the main thread only. You can use the `CGBitmapContext` from any thread.